# Jupyter notebook on cloud with nohup

Tags: google-compute-engine, jupyter, nohup

I would like to run jupyter notebook on Google instance and be able to use it even after I close web-based terminal window. Normally, I would launch jupyter notebook on Google instance using command `jupyter notebook`, then it would display something like:

```
http://localhost:8123/?token=16f1119a8e5f2ea87f82d8ff94cd9fde771a67acd800c135
```

I paste this string into my browser ( with some ssh prior to it) and it gives me jupyter notebook screen.

So I read that I can use `nohup` to be able to keep using jupyter after web-based terminal is closed. However, this comman `nohup jupyter notebook` generates:

```
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'
```

so I don't get to see connection string. I check content of `nohup.out` and it is empty. How can I get connection string with `nohup` command running?

Comment: It seems to me that you are establishing an SSH tunnel to the GCE VM and then accessing the application remotely in your browser (i.e. "http://localhost:8123/..", if that is the case, you must maintain the SSH tunnel opened so that your HTTP traffic can travel through it. In case you are trying is to run the tunnel in the background you can refer to [this URL](https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=455311).

Comment: You might also be interested in [this discussion Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43402138/how-do-i-connect-to-a-dataproc-cluster-with-jupyter-notebooks-from-cloud-shell/43409519#43409519)